# Evaluate formula in Go

Tags: go

Using Go (golang) I'd like to take a string with a formula and evaluate it with pre-defined values. Here's a way to do it with python's `parser` module:

```
x = 8
code = parser.expr("(x + 2) / 10").compile()
print eval(code)
# prints 1
```

Any idea how to do it with Go?

Comment: You can use [go-exprtk](https://github.com/Pramod-Devireddy/go-exprtk) package to evaluate these kinds of expressions.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This package will probably work for your needs: https://github.com/Knetic/govaluate

```
expression, err := govaluate.NewEvaluableExpression("(x + 2) / 10");

parameters := make(map[string]interface{}, 8)
parameters["x"] = 8;

result, err := expression.Evaluate(parameters);
```

Answer (score 15):

You will probably need to resort to a library that interprets math statements or have to write your own parser. Python being a dynamic language can parse and execute python code at runtime. Standard Go cannot do that.

If you want to write a parser on your own, the go package will be of help. Example ([On play](http://play.golang.org/p/h5jwskd4RI)):

```
import (
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
)

func main() {
    fs := token.NewFileSet()
    tr, _ := parser.ParseExpr("(3-1) * 5")
    ast.Print(fs, tr)
}
```

The resulting AST (Abstract Syntax Tree) can then be traversed and interpreted as you choose (handling '+' tokens as addition for the now stored values, for example).

Comment: Good answer, I'd only like to add  a sample how to actually eval expression: [On play](http://play.golang.org/p/MU2fg7KjjY). Global scope `types.Universe` can be used to declare consts (vars) used in the expression, for ex. I used `types.NewConst` and `types.Universe.Insert()` to fill it. Use `tv, err := types.Eval(fs, nil, token.NoPos, "a + b >= 5")` to eval expression, and `constant.BoolVal(tv.Value)` to get it's value. Sorry, all code doesn't fit into comment.

Comment: great. We just need to replace the params to get the expression go can exec.

Comment: And how to get the result of `ParseExpr`?

Comment: Can we initialize variables with values using this approach like in python you can write exec("a = 10") and after this you have a variable a=10

Comment: You can *parse* every statement the Go parser understands (or the parser you are using). You *cannot* run code in standard Go since it is a compiled language, thus `exec("a = 10")` won't work that way. Of course you can parse this input, evaluate the resulting abstract syntax tree and create variables, assign the values and do with those what you want afterwards. This is basically what `govaluate` does, see [@swill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40753302/1643939).

Answer (score 4):

I have  made my own *equation evaluator*, using `Djikstra's Shunting Yard Algorithm`.
It supports all operators, nested parenthesis, functions and even user defined variables.

It is written in pure `go`

https://github.com/marcmak/calc

Comment: Would be great if there was an example for how to use this to solve the specified problem since there is no documentation in the actual library.

Answer (score 2):

With this [code](https://play.golang.org/p/xfOtsVJ9lmF) you can evaluate dynamically any formula and return true or false:

```
package main

import (
    "go/token"
    "go/types"
)

func main() {
    fs := token.NewFileSet()
    tv, err := types.Eval(fs, nil, token.NoPos, "(1 + 4) >= 5")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    println(tv.Value.String())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[go-exprtk](https://github.com/Pramod-Devireddy/go-exprtk) package will probably meet all kinds of your needs to evaluate any kind of mathematical expression dynamically.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/Pramod-Devireddy/go-exprtk"
)

func main() {
    exprtkObj := exprtk.NewExprtk()

    exprtkObj.SetExpression("(x + 2) / 10")

    exprtkObj.AddDoubleVariable("x")

    exprtkObj.CompileExpression()
    
    exprtkObj.SetDoubleVariableValue("x", 8)

    fmt.Println(exprtkObj.GetEvaluatedValue())
}
```

This package has many [capabilities](https://github.com/Pramod-Devireddy/go-exprtk#-features)

Answer (score 1):

There is no such module in Go. You have to build your own. You could use subpackages of the [go](http://golang.org/pkg/go/) package, but they might be overkill for your application.

Comment: Hmm, I rather think it would be overkill to implement the parsing by yourself?

Comment: nemo: For simple expression evalution you might need far less than a full-blown lexer / parser combination. Also, you might want to have syntax that deviates from Go's syntax.

Comment: Yes, would've been nice to see that comment in your answer though :)

Answer (score 1):

For expression or program evaluation, you can build a lexer and parser using lex and yacc, and specify exactly the syntax and semantics of your mini-language. A calculator has always been a standard yacc example, and the go versions of lex and yacc are no different.

Here's a pointer to the calc example: https://github.com/golang-samples/yacc/tree/master/simple

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built in that could do that (remember, Go is not a dynamic language).

However, you can always use [bufio.Scanner](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) and build your own parser.

Answer (score 0):

Googling around I found this: https://github.com/sbinet/go-eval

It appears to be an eval loop for Go.

```
go get github.com/sbinet/go-eval/cmd/go-eval
go install github.com/sbinet/go-eval/cmd/go-eval
go-eval
```

Answer (score 0):

This package also a good fit https://github.com/antonmedv/expr

```
// Allow only admins and moderators to moderate comments.
user.Group in ["admin", "moderator"] || user.Id == comment.UserId


// Ensure all tweets are less than 240 characters.
all(Tweets, .Size <= 240)
```

Expr is a safe, fast, and intuitive expression evaluator optimized for the Go language. Here are its standout features:

- Memory-Safe
- Side-Effect-Free
- Always Terminating
- Seamless with Go
- Static Typing
- Optimized for Speed